Как заставить бота реагировать на фото с текстом?
Нужно сделать так, чтобы бот реагировал на картинку с определенным текстом ниже.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Вешайте фильтры на хендлер. Что-нибудь типа такого: F.photo, F.caption == 'Test'
